Convolve2d (Scipy): Treatment of Boundary Values
I am performing an averaging procedure where I want to average each element of a two-dimensional array over a field of 250x250 elements. I use:
A=u
kernel = np.ones((250, 250), dtype='int')
B = (convolve2d(A, kernel, mode='same')/convolve2d(np.ones_like(A), kernel, mode='same'))

with A.shape=(637, 589). When I plot the field, there appears a white frame near the edges. I assume that this is due to a wrong treatment of the boundary values.

Is the calculation that I perform correct? Is it possible to treat the boundary elements in a different way such that the structures remain visible?

You haven't specified what you want the boundary values to be, so the default boundary='fill' is used. Have a look at the documentation and find a boundary value that suits you.

@beaker, specifying the boundary option does not change the outcome...

I think that to get the behaviour you want you will need to zero pad A with a boundary of (at least) 250 zeroes on each side and then allow the convolutions to use periodic translation boundary conditions. I think mode full boundary fill might do what you want. Also try averaging over 125x125 and the pale zone should be reduced. You might also consider using a Gaussian kernel. Convolving with a top hat function is a bit brutal. I suspect you could rescale your output to correct for the loss of intensity at the edges. Feed in a test piece consisting of a bright cross on black background.

You should be using ndimage.uniform_filter instead as this takes into account that your filter is separable, and will be significantly faster.
